# How to check for type errors in dart

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Is there a way to check for type errors in Dart without going through Javascript transpilation? What if I don't want to make it Javascript and only run dart code? The Dart Editor gives me warnings, but isn't there a "compile" step I could use?

The only way I found to get some type checking was by transpiling my app to Javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531798/is-there-no-type-checking-in-a-list-of-maps-in-dart

Comment: So I really have to execute the code in checked mode? I guess unit testing things in checked mode becomes useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analyzer does this.

`dartanalyzer options libraries`

`dartanalyzer` can be found in the `dart-sdk/bin` directory.

You can also build using `dart2dart` instead of `dart2js`.
See [Run Dart WebApp on Apache Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672090) how to configure it.

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I can't find `dart2dart` however, for those wondering you can call `dart2js --output-type=dart yourFile.dart`

Comment: It's easier using `pub build` with the `$dart2js` transformer configuration shown in the answer I linked to.